# count records and join tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have tow tables that i want to join below are the details of the tables

`Trophy_lookup` table contains

```
id | user_id | trophy_id
1  | 2       | 2
2  | 3       | 4
3  | 1       | 5
4  | 2       | 1
4  | 1       | 1
```

`Users` table contains general user information

```
id | name    | email
1  | john    | john@webcom
2  | jacky   | jacky@web.com
3  | Smith   | smith@web.com
4  | Rob     | rob@web.com
```

**Problem**
I want to join `users` and `trophy_lookup` table in a way that i can count how many trophis a user win along with user name Below is my desired output that i want to achieve.

```
user_id| name | count(trophis)
     1 | john | 2
     2 | jacky| 2
```

So far i have tried many things but i am unable to achieve above results. I am not very good with writing queries, so Please guide me with this. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select in MySQL based on two tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022799/select-in-mysql-based-on-two-tables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query

```
select a.id, a.name, count(*) as cnt
from table2 a 
inner join 
table1 b
on a.id = b.user_id
group by 
a.id, a.name
having count(*) > 1
order by cnt
```

### **[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/39167/6)**:

```
| ID |  NAME | CNT |
--------------------
|  2 | jacky |   2 |
|  1 |  john |   2 |
```

Alternate approach

```
select a.name, b.* 
from table2 a
inner join 
(select a.id, count(*) as cnt
from table2 a 
inner join 
table1 b
on a.id = b.user_id
group by 
a.id) b 
ON a.id=b.id
where cnt > 1
```

### **[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/39167/5)**:

```
|  NAME | ID | CNT |
--------------------
|  john |  1 |   2 |
| jacky |  2 |   2 |
```

Comment: perfect, just one thing , can you modify yout query in a way that it display results having greater than 1 count ?

Comment: If you want results having greater than 1 count just give that condition in having clause: `select u.id,count(u.id),u.name from trophy_lookup t join users u on t.user_id=u.id group by u.id having count(u.id) > 1`

Comment: i am doing `ORDER BY` count(*) but it still showing the result in the same way the query output result without it

Comment: Try adding `order by cnt` check the edit... of the first query

Comment: it still displaying the same result set, Order By is not changing the result set :-(

Comment: :P I'm not getting your problem. It is working in the fiddle. If you want in descending order than add `order by cnt DESC`

Comment: Ooops ! i am sorry, i am so dumb sometimes, now it's all fine. Thanks you very much for your help, much appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT u.id,count(u.id),u.name 
FROM trophy_lookup t 
JOIN users u ON t.user_id=u.id 
GROUP BY u.id ;
```